# Is it possible to convert an arbitrary tensor defined using tf.placeholder to a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

I want to convert a tensor which is defined using tf.placeholder to a numpy array to be used in matplotlib. The tensors are defined using

```
def _create_train_input(self):
        self.lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='lr')
        self.label = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None], name='label')
        self.image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                    [None, None, None, self._n_channel],
                                    name='image')
        if self._is_transform:
            self.input_im = self._translate_image(self.image)
        else:
            self.input_im = self.image
        self.input_label = self.label
```

and I use the `self.input_im` tensor passed from another function to the following function where the list locations is populated during execution. (I am running this for image recognition with a recurrent neural network so multiple glimpse windows are used on the same image and the list contains the locations of those glimpse windows)

```
def draw_locations(self,inputs_im,size=8, epoch=0):
        image = inputs_im.numpy()
        locations = list(self.layers['loc_mean'])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(locations))
        for i, location in enumerate(locations):
            if len(locations) == 1:
                subplot = ax
            else:
                subplot = ax[i]
            subplot.axis('off')
            subplot.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
            loc = ((location[0] + 1) * image.shape[1] / 2 - size / 2,
             (location[1] + 1) * image.shape[0] / 2 - size / 2)
            # print(location, loc)
            rect = patches.Rectangle(
                loc, size, size, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
            subplot.add_patch(rect)
        fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=None, hspace=None)
        plt.savefig('results/glimpse_%d.png'%epoch, bbox_inches='tight')
        plt.close()
```

I have already enabled eager execution using tf.enable_eager_execution() but the the error still appears.
The error is

```
image = image12.numpy()
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: Also, as per the Tensorflow Documentation in the link , https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder#eager_compatibility, `Placeholders are not compatible with eager execution.`. You may have to `disable_eager_execution` and may have to run the `variable` you need in a `Session`.